# Paginación query post wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un problema con la paginación de mi template, ya me he dado vueltas google y nada.  Se ve la paginación numérica, también cambia la url a page=2, pero siguen viéndose los mismos posts. Adjunto código, ojalá puedan ayudarme.

```
            <?php query_posts("offset=1"); ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="whitelayer sombras">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <figure>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a>

                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 center-center">
                                <h3><?php the_category();?></h3>
                                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                                <p>Publicado el: <strong><?php the_date();?></strong></p>

                                <p><?php the_excerpt(25) ?></p>

                                <br>

                                <ul class="blog-footer">
                                    <li>Por: <strong><?php the_author();?></strong></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btns btn-blog" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">Continuar leyendo</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mb"></div>
            <?php endwhile;     ?>      
                <nav class="pagination">
                    <?php pagination_bar(); ?>
                </nav>

            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso el parámetro `offset` no es lo indicado, sino `paged` y en realidad tampoco usaría `query_posts()`. Intenta algo así:

```
$args = array( 'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
$wp_query = new WP_Query ( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta el parametro paged en $args. Debería quedarte así:

```
$args = array( 'paged' => $paged );
$args = array( 'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
```